# PrototypeJS :contains case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How to make :contains case-insensitive on PrototypeJS?

I am using this code to find an element.

var dtWarna = $$("dt:contains('Warna')").last();

Comment: Using `contains()` like that appears to be a jQuery thing, I don't see anything in Prototype with that exact signature. $$() wants any valid CSS[3] selector as its argument. The closest thing I can find in CSS (according to the W3C Selectors Level 3 RFC) is the `selector[attr*='something']` construction, but I don't see any way to target the text content using CSS, only the rel or class or any other valid attribute of the tag containing the text. In Prototype, you need to select all the DTs and filter them to find the ones that match that string, which you can do using `select()`.

Comment: @Walter because PrototypeJS and jQuery both use the Sizzle CSS engine `contains()` might be available depending on which version of PrototypeJS is loaded. However according to the Sizzle Docs, the `contains()` method is case sensitive and would need to be changed in Sizzle to solve Doni's problem